# passing host config to controller/service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller makes a $http.get request before scope is set by directive. How can I ensure that the required scope value is set first before the controller executes this ?

I have a directive ...

```
<mydir host="'localhost:8080'" api="/myapi/bla=?asdf=123"/>
```

Defined as ...

```
myapp.directive('mydir', function() {

    return{

        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/partials/dillist.html', 
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.host = attrs['host'];
            scope.api = attrs['api'];
        }

    }
});
```

My service ..

```
.service('MyService',function($http, $q){

        return{

            getPageData: function(host, api){
                $http.get(host+ api)
                ///some more stuff
            }

        }
    }
```

However my controller executes the service method before the directive has a chance to assign the properties from the directive to the scope.

```
// inside the controller //
MyService.getPageData($scope.host, $scope.api).then(function(res){
       ... some more code ..
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this with your current architecture is probably to move your getPageData call to a $watch function on the scope.

Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('[host,api]'), function() {
   if ($scope.host && $scope.api)
       MyService.getPageData($scope.host, $scope.api).then(function(res){
          ... some more code ..
       });
}, true);
```

Comment: I wonder if you have any advice for separating this out in a better structure using DI etc.. I have a feeling Unit Tests will be hard to write for this. thanks W

Comment: I can't think of anything dramatically better.  Angular feels a little awkward when you are pulling data out of templates instead of injecting it in.   I think unit testing might actually be okay with this method.  You'll create the controller, then set host and api on the scope, watch it call out to the service, have the mock http service feed it back some dummy data, and then see what it does with it.